# Aggregating vector object values matching with a key

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, mapreduce, aggregate

I've a vector made with struct that has a string and an int. The data is like this:

```
John 100
Jacob 90
Blake 99
Andy 105
John 65
Blake 70
Jacob 75
```

I've to print the name with the highest aggregate score. In this case, the added up scores will be like this

```
Blake 169
Jacob 165
John 165
Andy 105
```

So I've to print Blake 169. Once the scores are aggregated, the sorting isn't much of a problem, but how do I get the aggregation done first? So much like MapReduce. A simple code will be ideal as this is part of a program that is already a bit slow. Thanks.

I ended up just using loops and another vector. Anyone have any other fancy methods? Lambda maybe?

```
template <typename T>    
std::vector<T> aggregateSortVecs(std::vector<T> a)
{
    int q = 0;
    std::vector<T> final;
    while (q < a.size())
    {
        double total = a[q].data;
        for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++)
        {
            if (a[q].key == a[i].key)
            {
                total += a[i].data;
            }
        }
        final.push_back(T(a[q].key, total));
        q++;
    }

    sort(final.begin(), final.end(), [](const T &lhs, const T &rhs) {
        return lhs.data > rhs.data;
    });
    return final;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you've written to solve the problem.

Comment: You have a list of key-value-pairs? You want to aggregate them by theirs keys? AND you want them sorted? Then you will love [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: @cigien updated with what I did

Comment: Thank you, that's much better :) I've voted to reopen.